# Why is WhoId null for task created by email from Outlook plugin?

Tags: apex, trigger, email

I developed a simple trigger to fire before insert on task hoping to capture the whoId for the completed task that is inserted from using the Side Panel in Outlook.  I am trying to get WhoId for the task object but it is null.  Can someone explain how WhoId can be null but the task is still associated with the contact in Salesforce (Shows in Activity History).

Again, completed task is created from sending email through Outlook.

```
//Trigger fires when task from inbound email is created
  for(task t: trigger.new){
     system.debug('**** the whoid is ' + t.whoid);  // whoid = Null. Process stops here.
  }
```

Comment: What code creates the Task from Outlook? I suggest you try changing this to an After Insert trigger. It could be there's something in workflow or other code that creates the association between the contact on the inbound email in Outlook and the Who.Id. All you've posted is a for loop with no other context to go on. Is there an inbound email handler, is this Email to Salesforce or some other service?

Comment: I am using the Outlook plugin (side panel) to store the email on the contact record.  That is how the completed activity is created.  I have tried an after insert trigger but the whoId is still null.  There is not an inbound email handler.

Comment: an idea (I haven't used Outlook plugin before so this is a hypothetical workaround): workflow on Task when whoId != null and customField__c is false. Workflow field update sets customField__c to true causing Task before update trigger to fire. WhoId now known to trigger.

Comment: @crop1645  Thanks for your suggestion.  I tried your recommendation this morning and it turned out your solution does cause my trigger to fire before update; however, there was a bit more at play.  Since a completed activity was being created from the Outlook plugin, I needed to query contact and activityHistory with a sub-query.  Then I was able to get the whoid from the completed activity.